# center element css 3d transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have a css 3d transforms site. There are several css 3d positioned elements, including some nested inside of other 3d transformed elements. All of the transformed elements are inside of one big containing element. The container also have transforms on it, and it is inside of an even bigger wrapper. When one of the transformed elements is clicked, I want the container to transform so that the clicked element centers into the middle of the screen. After being centered, I would also like for it to be zoomed into so it takes up most of the screen

A simplified example of what I want: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/3Y4ww/2/embedded/result/)

the difference is this is just simple and non-dynamic. In my situation, the elements will be positioned at different places for different users

and one thing: `NO JQUERY!`

Comment: I don't use it. But if this can be done in jQuery I would still be curious to know how.

Comment: and yes, it is bulky.

Comment: Ah right I get it now: you are using mootools, right? Would it be okay to use that?

Comment: Ah yes, the old StackOverflow jQuery superiority complex

Comment: You need to elaborate on that Luke.

Comment: @jsalonen http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: Is there ANYBODY in stackoverflow who doesn't use jQuery or some other library for people who can't code for themselves?

Comment: @Markasoftware This is entirely of topic, but usage of libraries is not a matter of not knowing how to code, but a matter of productivity. There are a lot of common problems that these libraries solve with grace and minimal work -- in fact if you roll out your own custom solutions the chances are you won't beat a good library. Just consider for instance cross-browser compatibility -- getting that stuff right requires crazy amount of testing, but comes free with libraries like jQuery.

Comment: Btw. I still don't know whether you would accept mootools solution or require vanilla JavaScript+DOM.

Comment: No libraries whatsoever. No mootools. No jQuery. No HTML9 responsive boilerstrap (http://html9responsiveboilerstrapjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is `transform: scale()`

Working example here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y4ww/3/)

Just add this to your function: `scale(1.5)` as seen below.

```
transformed.onclick=function(){
    if(isTransformed){
        container.style.transform='';
        container.style.webkitTransform='';
        isTransformed=false;
    }
    else{
        container.style.transform='rotateY(-70deg) scale(1.5)';
        container.style.webkitTransform='rotateY(-70deg) scale(1.5)';
        isTransformed=true;
```

Comment: Sorry that my question was unclear, but this isn't exactly what I was trying to get. I actually want to center the element in the middle, not just make it bigger.

Comment: @Markasoftware then change the css-margins and make it position absolute, so that it leaves the dom flow. the nice thing about having a transition on it is that it will make margin changes also take time.

Comment: I want all of the containing elements to transform so that it is in the center. In the real thing, there is more than one element.

Comment: @Markasoftware well? What have you tried? Show me what you have and why it doesn't work. Then I might be able to help.

Comment: I want to know how to do it. I don't have much experience with 3d stuff

Answer (score 0):

Want you want is some geometry api to transform points from one coordinate-system to another, like "localToGlobal". Currently there is no api for Geometry like the Firefox [GeometryUtils](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/04/coordinate-conversion-made-easy/) api (FF >43). Chrome dropped there api: webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode some versions ago. I think IE10+ supports the webkitConvertPointFromPageToNode function.

You can take a look at my just-for-fun [library](https://github.com/jsidea/jsidea) (not stable yet), which can be used as polyfill for the GeometryUtils. So long you don not use perspective, it should be easy. Just transform your reference points (topLeft, topRight, ...) to local element's parent (or offsetParent) space and create a matrix:

```
var tx = localTopLeft;
var ty = localTopRight;
var scaleX = (localTopRight - tx) / element.offsetWidth;
var scaleY = (localBottomRight - ty) / element.offsetHeight;
var rawMatrix = [scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, tx, ty];
element.style.transformOrigin = "0px 0px";
element.style.transform = "matrix(" + rawMatrix.join(",") + ")";
```

If it becomes more complex, try using some "AffineFit" algorithm to create the matrix.

Good luck